# RegOpenKeyEx() returns ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry, regedit

I want to get all the CLSIDs keys that are under the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\SOFTWARE\\Classes\\CLSID` key.

I know that that key is mirror for merged `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Classes\\CLSID` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\Classes\\CLSID` keys.

So far I can enumerate all `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\SOFTWARE\\Classes\\CLSID` (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\...` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\...` as well) and get that key's names into `std::wstring[]`. But when I try to open that keys:

```
//CLSID = e.g. L"{CAFEEFAC-0013-0001-0001-ABCDEFFEDCBB}"
firstKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
keysPath = L"\\SOFTWARE\\Classes\\CLSID\\"+CLSID;
if(x64System)
    regsam = KEY_ALL_ACCESS|KEY_WOW64_64KEY; //on my system
else
    regsam = KEY_ALL_ACCESS;

result = RegOpenKeyEx(firstKey, keysPath.c_str(), 0, regsam, &outputKey);
```

It works **only** for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` it returns `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. Even when I **run my program as administrator** (in *regedit.exe* I can see that **key's name is good,** if it wouldn't error message would be not found, not `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` anyway).

**So what should I do to access that keys?** I'm sure that some programs can access that keys. Or at least how to get their default value (it is all I want from them)?

In my program I can only list their names with `RegQueryInfoKey` but cannot access them with `RegOpenKeyEx`.

Comment: You're not going to have write access to HKLM.  Replace `KEY_ALL_ACCESS` with `KEY_READ`.

Comment: Why are you using `KEY_ALL_ACCESS`?

Comment: The merged view of `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes` and `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes` is located at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID`, not at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even as an admin you don't have KEY_ALL_ACCESS on HKLM when UAC is enabled. If you want or need KEY_ALL_ACCESS you Need to run your program elevated.

Reduce your rights to the needed Level. If you only want to read just use KEY_READ!

And take care that you have an embedded manifest, without a manifest you might get access, but tis access is virtualized and you don't get access to the real key.

Comment: Or even better, use `KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS`, since you probably don't need the other rights that `KEY_READ` includes.

Comment: Thx to both of you. Changing flags worked perfectly :) I indeed don't need to write anything to the key, reading it is enough.